# Neural network to classify gender from username

Tags: neural-networks

Does anyone know of a trained net that can classify gender from username from any website? It would be nice if there is something in Wolfram Neural Net Repository or something that can be easily imported and used in Wolfram Framework.

I am performing data analysis on a dataset from a website but it lacks the gender field. It however has the username. I would like to add a predicted gender field so I can preform some analysis. Please if someone know of such a net I want to know.

If it helps I also have user's country of origin which might help disambiguate some username's gender.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/818203/does-anyone-know-of-a-good-library-for-mapping-a-persons-name-to-his-or-her-gen

Comment: Seeing **your** username, I wonder how you came to the idea of classifying users' gender by username...

Comment: his/her username is related to her/his reputation

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher I am not classifying user name from this website. Also I understand some will still remain ambiguous but that is ok where it is impossible.

Comment: @J42161217 Hah! Indeed! =D

Comment: Just a coincidence guys (reputation at the moment: 1389), a great one indeed ;)

Comment: @user13892 you’d likely be able to further determine ambiguous usernames by their connections to others who’s genders have a higher percentage weight to their determined gender (this is probably so rough of a generalization, but it’s akin to finding connections between blogs and determining politics purely based on their connections to other blogs and the amount of traffic which feeds into them, and from where)

Comment: Why voting the question down?

Answer (score 1):

```
Classify["NameGender", "Alexey"]
```

> "Male"

Comment: I wouldn't trust this classifier: it already bugs out on `Classify["NameGender", "Andrea"]` as *Mathematica* thinks it's a female name and doesn't admit it's [highly ambiguous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andrea).

Comment: I tried this. This does not appear to be a real classifier, as it gives Probability 50-50 or `Indeterminate` for all cases which it doesn't "explicitly" know about. It looks like a basic name lookup rather than a machine learning classifier. It has no intelligence to infer the gender.

Comment: @Roman There's `Classify["NameGender", "Andrea", "Probabilities"]`, but in this case it thinks it's 99% female.

Comment: Thanks @kirma that's a useful indicator. Yes 99% female is a bit suspicious for a name that literally means "man" :)

Comment: Apart from 50-50 probabilities, it's very rare to see this classifier taking an uncertain stance, that is more than 1% for the losing gender. Out of several unisex English names only couple rise above 2%, Riley being an extreme case at 55-45.

Comment: @Roman I don't think "andr-" part turns it necessarily male; consider Alexandros/Alexandra, "male/female defender of the people" if I am not mistaken.